# Xamarin Forms - Return object from modal

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to work out how to return a object from a modal.

I am using MessagingCenter.

My code is as follows, but it does not enter the subscribe.

For the  subscribe in Register:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Register, PublicUtilityDamage>(this,"UtilityCompanySelected", async (sender, Company) => {
            await DisplayAlert("Company Selected", Company.DamageType, "OK");
        });
```

And for the send code which is in the modal:

```
MessagingCenter.Send(company, "UtilityCompanySelected");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to be sure the type arguments for the sender and subscriber match - the first  should be the Type of the page/class that is SENDING the message.  And when sending, the third parameter is the argument you are passing.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SelectDamageType, PublicUtilityDamage>(this,"UtilityCompanySelected", async (sender, Company) => {
            await DisplayAlert("Company Selected", Company.DamageType, "OK");
        });

MessagingCenter.Send<SelectDamageType, PublicUtilityDamage>(this, "UtilityCompanySelected", company);
```

Comment: Hello, The following line of code does not work: MessagingCenter.Send<Register, PublicUtilityDamage>(this, "UtilityCompanySelected", company);. Thats because "this" points to the modal page.

Comment: the first type argument <T> in the Send and Subscribe needs to refer to the  type of the page that is SENDING the message.

Comment: "Cannot convert from SelectDamageType to Register" is the error message, if thats of any use :)

Comment: which one is the class that is SENDING the message?

Comment: SelectDamageType is sending

Comment: Thanks, that worked! there seems to be an alternative way also though, and that is to set the first Type to match that of the subscribing class/page.